# Html5 QRcode scanner library not closing camera after scan

Tags: camera, qr-code

I use this library for qrcode scan https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode

It works fine but I can't stop camera after successful scan and camera stays open all the time after usage.

This is the code I used, and I use suggested stop function too but not working.

```
docReady(function () {
var resultContainer = document.getElementById('qr-reader-results');
var lastResult, countResults = 0;
function onScanSuccess(decodedText, decodedResult) {
    if (decodedText !== lastResult) {
        ++countResults;
        lastResult = decodedText;
        // Handle on success condition with the decoded message.
        console.log(`Scan result ${decodedText}`, decodedResult);

        

        add_my_by_qr_code(decodedText);

        html5QrcodeScanner.stop().then((ignore) => {
          // QR Code scanning is stopped.
        }).catch((err) => {
          // Stop failed, handle it.
        });

       

    }
}

var html5QrcodeScanner = new Html5QrcodeScanner(
    "qr-reader", { fps: 10, qrbox: 250 });
html5QrcodeScanner.render(onScanSuccess);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to trigger click event on library's "Stop Camera" button which is shown when camera is active.

```
jQuery way 
$("#html5-qrcode-button-camera-stop").trigger("click");

Pure JS
document.getElementById("html5-qrcode-button-camera-stop").click();
```

But it is better to check whether the button is active and also the scanner division visible (if you are showing scanner after a button is clicked)

```
  if (
          $("#html5-qrcode-button-camera-stop").length 
          && 
          !$('#qr-reader').is(':visible')
    ) 
    $("#html5-qrcode-button-camera-stop").trigger("click");
```

Answer (score 0):

The function to stop the camera is associated with the object html5Qrcode inside the scanner object, so the code inside the handler should be:

```
html5QrcodeScanner.html5Qrcode.stop()
```

This stops the camera, but leaves you with some strange elements on the screen, like a green border where the scanning area was. I don't know if this was supposed to not be called or if this is a bug.

In my case, I didn't need the scanner after I got the result, so I called the general function to remove the whole scanner from the screen, by calling the Html5QrcodeScanner#clear function:

```
html5QrcodeScanner.clear();
```

Refs.: https://scanapp.org/html5-qrcode-docs/docs/apis/classes/Html5QrcodeScanner#clear: